# Using If statements to conditionally populate a field in Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to use the field calculator to poplulate a string field in a table based on info in another string field. This is what I have:

```
def Reclass(Correction_Comments):
     if (MSAGSTREETNAME) = 'HEMLOCK':
         return 'IN PARCEL 103'
```

In the call box:

```
Reclass( !Correction_Comments!)
```

I keep getting a parsing error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter "Correction_Comments" from your function is not used at all within the function. Instead, there is a variable "MSAGSTREETNAME", a local variable that is not referenced elsewhere. In addition, the if statement is using an assignment (=) rather than a test (==).

Modifications:

```
def Reclass(streetnamefield):
     if streetnamefield == 'HEMLOCK':
         return 'IN PARCEL 103'


Reclass( !Correction_Comments!)
```

This will pass the field `Correction_Comments` into your `Reclass` function. You may instead want to run this in the Field Calculator for the `Correction_Comments` field, against the `MGAGSTREETNAME` field e.g. right click `Correction_Comments`, Field Calculator, and run with `Reclass(!MGAGSTREETNAME!)`.